# Pure CSS Parallax - Text Hiding Under Parallax Picture After Scrolling

Tags: css, parallax

I'm trying to make the text of this parallax effect NOT to scroll down at the same as the effect.

I believe it has something to do with the html CSS code(overflow), I've tried putting into different places but it did not work. Is there any way to make my parallax work as it is now and while  you scroll down the text will still be fully visible? Cause as soon as you scroll down the parallax AND the text scroll as well but by the time you reach the text, some have already scrolled up.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  perspective: 1px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: "Luna"
}

header {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 30vw 0 5vw;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: inherit;
  width: 100vw;
}

header h1 {
  margin-top: -100px;
}

header,
header:before {
  background: 50% 50% / cover;
}

header:before {
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  background-image: url('../img/lake.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  transform-origin: center center 0;
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
  z-index: -1;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header * {
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em 0;
}

p {
  color: grey;
}

.container {
  max-width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Parallax Effect</h1>
  <p>Pure CSS // No JavaScript!</p>
</header>

<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dictum interdum lectus vel commodo. Etiam massa augue, fermentum vel elit ut, lobortis pellentesque quam. Nulla pellentesque, velit in accumsan hendrerit, magna mauris congue odio, at
    maximus quam est in nisl. Mauris placerat eros dapibus commodo congue. Cras a sollicitudin nulla, at varius lorem. Quisque malesuada rhoncus orci, et convallis metus semper in. Donec vulputate sit amet lectus vitae consequat. Etiam convallis odio
    eget diam pretium, et molestie tortor imperdiet. Duis sapien felis, auctor sed mattis a, pretium non nisi. Proin dui metus, tempor ut viverra ac, laoreet ut erat. Sed sollicitudin lorem aliquam, tincidunt mi quis, imperdiet risus.</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dictum interdum lectus vel commodo. Etiam massa augue, fermentum vel elit ut, lobortis pellentesque quam. Nulla pellentesque, velit in accumsan hendrerit, magna mauris congue odio, at
    maximus quam est in nisl. Mauris placerat eros dapibus commodo congue. Cras a sollicitudin nulla, at varius lorem. Quisque malesuada rhoncus orci, et convallis metus semper in. Donec vulputate sit amet lectus vitae consequat. Etiam convallis odio
    eget diam pretium, et molestie tortor imperdiet. Duis sapien felis, auctor sed mattis a, pretium non nisi. Proin dui metus, tempor ut viverra ac, laoreet ut erat. Sed sollicitudin lorem aliquam, tincidunt mi quis, imperdiet risus.</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dictum interdum lectus vel commodo. Etiam massa augue, fermentum vel elit ut, lobortis pellentesque quam. Nulla pellentesque, velit in accumsan hendrerit, magna mauris congue odio, at
    maximus quam est in nisl. Mauris placerat eros dapibus commodo congue. Cras a sollicitudin nulla, at varius lorem. Quisque malesuada rhoncus orci, et convallis metus semper in. Donec vulputate sit amet lectus vitae consequat. Etiam convallis odio
    eget diam pretium, et molestie tortor imperdiet. Duis sapien felis, auctor sed mattis a, pretium non nisi. Proin dui metus, tempor ut viverra ac, laoreet ut erat. Sed sollicitudin lorem aliquam, tincidunt mi quis, imperdiet risus.</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dictum interdum lectus vel commodo. Etiam massa augue, fermentum vel elit ut, lobortis pellentesque quam. Nulla pellentesque, velit in accumsan hendrerit, magna mauris congue odio, at
    maximus quam est in nisl. Mauris placerat eros dapibus commodo congue. Cras a sollicitudin nulla, at varius lorem. Quisque malesuada rhoncus orci, et convallis metus semper in. Donec vulputate sit amet lectus vitae consequat. Etiam convallis odio
    eget diam pretium, et molestie tortor imperdiet. Duis sapien felis, auctor sed mattis a, pretium non nisi. Proin dui metus, tempor ut viverra ac, laoreet ut erat. Sed sollicitudin lorem aliquam, tincidunt mi quis, imperdiet risus.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `container` class needs to be positioned relative to its parent for it to show up in front of the parallax background.

```
.container {
  max-width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

You'll need to add some background color to separate it visually as well.

Here's a [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/tribex/pen/mWNWdz) with a similar effect and its [accompanying article](https://alligator.io/css/pure-css-parallax/).

Comment: Adding the position relative won't change the fact that the text is still rolling with the parallax. :(

thank you for the links, I will read them now to see if I understand a bit better! :)

Comment: The effect Im trying to replicate is this one: https://youtu.be/6CQ7DYni7Bg?t=11s

When I put a text bellow there, my text goes behind the parallax! :(

Comment: Check out [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/bliu1/pen/zJGrox). I added some padding and background color to the container class.